# Stream Android live audio to pc

Tags: android, audio

I want to record live audio, and transfer it to PC, then play it on PC.

I found a sample on net.

```
public class Saudioclient extends Thread {

    protected AudioRecord m_in_rec;
    protected int m_in_buf_size;
    protected byte[] m_in_bytes;
    protected boolean m_keep_running;
    protected Socket s;
    protected DataOutputStream dout;
    protected LinkedList<byte[]> m_in_q;

    public void run() {
        try {
            byte[] bytes_pkg;
            m_in_rec.startRecording();
            while (m_keep_running) {
                m_in_rec.read(m_in_bytes, 0, m_in_buf_size);
                bytes_pkg = m_in_bytes.clone();
                if (m_in_q.size() >= 2) {
                    dout.write(m_in_q.removeFirst(), 0,
                            m_in_q.removeFirst().length);
                }
                m_in_q.add(bytes_pkg);
            }

            m_in_rec.stop();
            m_in_rec = null;
            m_in_bytes = null;
            dout.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        m_in_buf_size = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        m_in_rec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, m_in_buf_size);

        m_in_bytes = new byte[m_in_buf_size];

        m_keep_running = true;
        m_in_q = new LinkedList<byte[]>();

        try {
            s = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 4332);
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            // new Thread(R1).start();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The Android device still sounds.This is not what I want.I want the live audio is only played on PC, not on the Android device.

Any suggestion?

Comment: _"The Android device still sounds."_ I see nothing in the code you've put in your question that indicates that you're playing the recorded audio on the device. How are you using this class? Do you have an `AudioTrack` or `MediaPlayer` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: The recorded audio is transferred to PC(or other device) and

Comment: My Android device is called device A.I want to get the audio from device A's speaker, transfer it then play it on another device called device B in short.At the same time, device A keeps silent.But If I use AudioRecord class, I've no idea how to keep device A silent.